# show process's full command line in powershell?

Tags: powershell

When I run this command

`PS C:\> gwmi Win32_Process | select CommandLine`

It cuts off the command line. How can I get it to show the full command line?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That being done by the default formatting, which is using `Format-Table`.  Try format-list

```
gwmi win32_process | select commandline | format-list
```

Comment: Fixed.  Didn't mean to include the -expandproperty

Comment: thanks, that works too and nicely.. out of interest, if you remove format-list and use -ExpandProperty CommandLine, then how do you get two properties like gwmi Win32_Process | select Handle, -ExpandProperty CommandLine    I get an error with that one

Comment: `-ExpandProperty` only allows a single propertyname, and `-ExpandPropert` can't be combined with other "normal" properties.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively Format-Table offers the -wrap and -autosize parameters.

```
gwmi win32_process | select handle, commandline | ft -wrap -autosize
```

Results

```
466    %SystemRoot%\system32\csrss.exe ObjectDirectory=\Windows SharedSection=1024,20480,768 Windows=On SubSystemType=Windows ServerDll=bas
       esrv,1 ServerDll=winsrv:UserServerDllInitialization,3 ServerDll=winsrv:ConServerDllInitialization,2 ServerDll=sxssrv,4 ProfileContro
       l=Off MaxRequestThreads=16
550    wininit.exe
510    %SystemRoot%\system32\csrss.exe ObjectDirectory=\Windows SharedSection=1024,20480,768 Windows=On SubSystemType=Windows ServerDll=bas
       esrv,1 ServerDll=winsrv:UserServerDllInitialization,3 ServerDll=winsrv:ConServerDllInitialization,2 ServerDll=sxssrv,4 ProfileContro
       l=Off MaxRequestThreads=16
546    C:\Windows\system32\services.exe
596    C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe
3472   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
1766   "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
3384   "C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
1780   \??\C:\Windows\system32\conhost.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

You're better off filtering for specific process which can be done via PID or Process Name, both pieces of information are easily obtained from the task manager if you don't already know.

Once you have the PID this will work great:

```
$PID=<Your Process ID)

(Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter ProcessId=$PID -Property CommandLine).CommandLine
```

Example of getting java.exe by process name:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_process -Filter "Name='java.exe'" -Property CommandLine).CommandLine
```

**added by barlop**

example with output-

```
PS C:\Users\User> (Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter ProcessId=1676 -Property CommandLine).CommandLine <ENTER>

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=1108,1777349067310493
8616,10462310811264875730,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-auto-reload --origin-trial-disabled-features=MeasureMemory --devi
ce-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=2 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=1695 --no-v8-untrust
ed-code-mitigations --mojo-platform-channel-handle=11412 /prefetch:1
PS C:\Users\User>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a frequently asked question about how powershell formats output.  Aside from making the window bigger:

```
gwmi Win32_Process | % CommandLine

sihost.exe
C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k UnistackSvcGroup
taskhostw.exe {222A245B-E637-4AE9-A93F-A59CA119A75E}
```

Note that `get-process` in powershell 7 has the commandline property too.  You can add it in powershell 5.1 like this in your $profile.  I wish the default table view for a powershell command could be updated as concisely.

```
$updateTypeData = @{
    TypeName   = 'System.Diagnostics.Process'
    MemberName = 'CommandLine'
    MemberType = [Management.Automation.PSMemberTypes]::ScriptProperty
    Force      = $true
    Value      = { (Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = 
                   $($this.Id)").CommandLine }
}
Update-TypeData @updateTypeData
```

```
get-process notepad | % commandline

"C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
```